# When does Gaussian elimination solve exact 1-in-3 SAT?

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability, linear-algebra, 3-sat

**Terms:**

A **literal** is a *variable* or its *negation*.

A **clause** is a *set* of literals.

An **exact 3-in-1 clause** is satisfied if an assignment of values to variables results in exactly 1 `true` literal and 2 `false` literals.

**Exact 3-in-1 SAT** is the problem, given a set of **exact 3-in-1 clauses**, is there as assignment of variables that satisfies all clauses?

**Question:**

This corresponds to a linear algebra problem, sort of:

Let `true` be `1` and `false` be `-1`.

For each variable `v` and its negation `w`, add the equations:

`v + w = 0`

(This is because `1 + (-1) = 0`)

For each exact 3-in-1 clause (`a` `b` `c`), add the equations:

`a + b + c = -1`

(This is because two `-1`'s and one `1` will add up to `-1`.)

It's possible solving the equations results in a value other than `1` or `-1`. However if the solution to the system of equations is only `1` and `-1`, I suspect that's a valid solution to the original exact 1-in-3 problem.

**So, when does Gaussian elimination solve exact 1-in-3 SAT?**

Here's an example when it does:

These clauses:

(`1` `2` `3`)
(`2` `3` `-2`)
(`2` `3` `-3`)

Correspond to this matrix:

```
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1
```

Reduced row echelon:

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
```

Therefore solution (via far-right column) is: (`1` `-2` `-3`)

**Does this always work on larger matrices with `2*n` rows and `2*n+1` columns where `n` is the number of variables?** (I think it may need non-redundant (linearly independent?) rows.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does this always work on larger matrices with 2*n rows and 2*n+1 columns where n is the number of variables? (I think it may need non-redundant (linearly independent?) rows.)

It works but since there are assignments other than -1 and 1, how will you use the row echelon form to make any conclusions about the 1-in-3 SAT instance?

It is possible that the 1-in-3SAT formula is unsatisfiable but the corresponding reduced row echelon matrix is satisfiable (because of the possible assignments other than -1/1), therefore you won't be able to rely on the matrix in the general case

**Gaussian elimination solves exact 1-in-3 SAT when the matrix form only has solutions with variables assigned to -1 or 1, or when the matrix is unsatisfiable**